# Strange results for solving boundary angle of full reflection

Tags: trigonometry, wolfram-alpha

I was trying to solve the following group of equations for $\alpha$ using Wolfram|Alpha:

$$\frac{v_2\cdot\sin(\alpha)}{v_1} = 1 \\
v_1 > 0 \\
v_2 > 0$$

I expected something like $\alpha = \sin^{-1}(\frac{v_1}{v_2})$ but instead got:
$$v_1 > 0\text{  and  }v_2>0\text{  and  }\alpha = 2 \pi n-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{v_1}{v_2}\right)+\pi\text{  and  }n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Can someone explain why Wolframp|Alpha gives this answer?

Comment: There are two angles whose $\sin$ is $v_1/v_2$ when $v_1\ne v_2$. One in the first quadrant and one in the second. The solution given by WA corresponds to the angle in the second.  Note adding an integer multiple of $2\pi$ to an angle gives an equivalent angle. (The solution in the first quadrant is $\sin^{-1}(v_1/v_2)$.  You can add integer multiples of $2\pi$ to this to obtain other solutions.)

Comment: @DavidMitra Will you post your answer as such?